# How flutter webview cannot update it's page after navigation

Tags: flutter, webview

I have this webview and buttons that navigates to another route (in flutter, not another page in web), and when I go back to the webview, the webview didnt respond to any updates until i move my cursor, even with setstate this doesnt seem to fix anything.

This is the button Im clicking after navigating back to the webview

```
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
        height: 48,
        width: 48,
        child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (widget.reportController.page <
                      widget.reportController.totalPages &&
                  widget.reportController.totalPages != 1 &&
                  widget.reportController.buttonClick == "") {
                widget.webViewController.runJavaScript("nextPageClick()");
                widget.reportController.toggleButtonClick("next");

                widget.reportController
                    .setCurrentPage(widget.reportController.page + 1);

                setState(() {});
              }
            },
      ),
```

and this is the channels that the backend called, these are supposed to change the page, but it doesnt **only** after navigating back and forth

```
      widget.webViewController.addJavaScriptChannel("RenderPageSVG",
          onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
        print("RenderPageSVG");
        widget.reportController.setSVGData(message.message);
        setState(() {});
      });
      widget.webViewController.addJavaScriptChannel("RenderPageSVGSize",
          onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
        print("RenderPageSVGSize");
        //set base page size
        Map<String, dynamic> msg = jsonDecode(message.message);
        widget.reportController.setsvgWidth(msg["width"]);
        widget.reportController.setsvgHeight(msg["height"]);
        setState(() {});
      });
      widget.webViewController.addJavaScriptChannel("RenderPageLinks",
          onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
        widget.reportController.toggleButtonClick("");
        print("RenderPageLinks");
        List<dynamic> linkListData = jsonDecode(message.message);
        //no link came out, test this part
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> finalLinkListData =
            linkListData.map((e) => e as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
        widget.reportController.setLinksData(finalLinkListData);
        setState(() {});
      });
```